# Document.oncontextmenu, component is not available (firefox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, greasemonkey

I have a script for a website, and one of the things ti does right at the end if attempt to disable an anti-right click protection in a website

```
if($("span[class=MembersNameDisplay]").exists()){
    var list_row = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    if(list_row != null){
        list_row[0].parentNode.removeChild(list_row[0]);
    }
}

document.oncontextmenu=new Function("return true");
```

In google chrome this works, however in firefox with greasemonkey, the last line fails and the protection is not removed.

```
Error: Component is not available Line: 171
```

How do I fix this, and why does it fail under firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Al little search on [Userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org/scripts/search?q=contextmenu) showed me multiple solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/greasemonkey-users/browse_frm/thread/3c37e0e9c87fb00f/f18f7b2c195c425a), which I have used for a mouseup event, you should be able something like `document.addEventListener("contextmenu", new Function("return true"), true)`.